# Show that the given integral is convergent

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

The task is to show that $\displaystyle{\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\dfrac{1}{e^{\mid t \mid}+\sin^2(t)}}$ converges.

My thought was that since $\sin^2(t)$ got the range [0,1], i could compare it as follows:

$\displaystyle{\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\dfrac{1}{e^{\mid t \mid}+\sin^2(t)}\leq \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \dfrac{1}{e^{\mid t \mid}}}$

And that converges to 2, so hence $\displaystyle{\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\dfrac{1}{e^{\mid t \mid}+\sin^2(t)}}$ is converget. Is my reasoning correct or did I stumble upon any errors in my logic along the way?

Comment: It is correct. You only need to use that $\sin^2(t)\ge0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are correct.

As an alternative, we can also refer to [limit comparison test](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Emconger/dhsp/lct.pdf) avoiding to make consideration on the sign of the $\sin^2(t)$ term, indeed since

$$\dfrac{e^{\mid t \mid}}{e^{\mid t \mid}+\sin^2(t)} \to 1$$

and $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \dfrac{1}{e^{\mid t \mid}}$ converges we can conclude that also the given integral converges.

Note that with limit comparison test it is also simpler to show convergence for the following integral

$$\displaystyle{\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\dfrac{1}{e^{\mid t \mid}+\sin(t)}}$$

for which the direct comparison test fails.